# Error en el codigo de registro de usuario, PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql

estoy programando un pequeña red social como practica de php y mysql, pero el codigo PHP de registro me aparece un error en la linea 34 con las sentecias preparadas, en el bind_param().

Fatal error: Call to a member function bind_param() on boolean in D:\Xammp2\htdocs\Bluefire\new_user.php on line 34

no se que signifa este error, se agredece cualquier ayuda.

```
<?php

$nombre=$_POST['user_name'];
$correo=$_POST['user_mail'];
$contraseña=$_POST['user_password'];
$sexo=$_POST['user_sex'];

if(!empty($nombre) || !empty($correo) || !empty($contraseña) || !empty($sexo) ) {

    $hosting = "localhost";
    $user = "root";
    $password = "";
    $database = "users";

    $conexion = new mysqli($hosting,$user,$password,$database);
    if (mysqli_connect_error()) {
        die("error de conexion(".mysqli_connect_errno().")". mysqli_connect_error());
    }

    else {
        $SELECT = "SELECT correo FROM usuarios WHERE correo = ? limit 1";
        $INSERT = "INSERT INTO usuarios (nombre,correo,contraseña,sexo) VALUES (?,?,?,?)";

        $stmt = $conexion->prepare($SELECT);
        $stmt ->bind_param( "s",$correo);
        $stmt ->execute();
        $stmt ->bind_result($correo);
        $stmt ->store_result();
        $rnum = $stmt->num_rows;

        if ($rnum == 0) {
            $stmt ->close();
            $stmt = $conexion->prepare($INSERT);
            $stmt ->bind_param( "ssss",$nombre,$correo,$contraseña,$sexo);
            $stmt ->execute();

            echo "Ya estas dentro ;).";
        } else {
            echo "Lo siento amigo, pero ese correo ya esta en uso";
        }
        $stmt->close;
        $conexion->close;
    }

} else {
    echo "¡Hey!, aun falta información";
    die();
}

?>
```

Comment: Que linea es la 34

Comment: Esa `ñ` en un nombre de columna y de variable podría darte problemas, lo he visto más de una vez. Deberías evitar el uso de `ñ`  y acentos para tus nombres de tabla/columnas/variables, si no hilas fino con la codificación te darán error. También, deberías controlar siempre todo aquello del código que pueda dar error. Prueba a poner el bloque de inserción dentro de un `if`, algo así: **`if ( $stmt = $conexion->prepare($INSERT) ) { #Aquí la insercion }  else { echo "Error: ".$conexion->error; }`** Así veremos si hay un problema insertando.